# Using combineAll to replace switchMap and map?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, angular2-services, side-effects

I tried to use `combineAll` to, well, combine all, I tried different combinations but could not get it work.
But I managed to get some working code by doing this ugly nesting with all these switchMap/map.
How can I achive the same result using `combineAll` ?

```
@Effect()
  SelectItem$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(supernode.ActionTypes.SET_SELECTED_ITEM)
    .debounceTime(100)
    .switchMap(() => {
      return this.itemService.isEditable().switchMap(
        edit => this.itemService.isSharable().switchMap(
          share => this.itemService.isListable().map(
            list => new item.SetShareStatus({
              listable: list, editable: edit, sharable: share
            })
          )
        )
      ).take(1);
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: Have you tried `combineLatest()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what all the functions you call should do but it seems to me you don't need to use neither `combineAll` nor `switchMap`. I think you would do better with `zip()` or `forkJoin()`:

```
.switchMap(() => Observable.forkJoin(
    this.itemService.isEditable()
    this.itemService.isSharable()
    this.itemService.isListable()
  ))
  .map(results => new SetShareStatus({
    listable: results[2], editable: results[1], sharable: results[1]
   }))
})
```

I think `combineLatest()` isn't a good choice because it emits when any of its source Observables emit which is I think what you don't want.

Answer (score 2):

I would propose to use `combineLatest` operator instead:

```
...
.switchMap(() =>
    Observable.combineLatest(
        this.itemService.isEditable(),
        this.itemService.isSharable(),
        this.itemService.isListable(),
        (editable, sharable, listable) =>
            new SetShareStatus({ editable, sharable, listable })
    )
    .take(1)
)
```

`combineAll` should be applied to a higher-order observable, i.e. to an observable of observables, so if you really want to use it, then you would need to create a higher-order observable out of your observables first, e.g.:

```
Observable.of(
    this.itemService.isEditable(),
    this.itemService.isSharable(),
    this.itemService.isListable()
)
.combineAll((editable, sharable, listable) =>
    new SetShareStatus({ editable, sharable, listable }))
```